# PHP incorrect precision while rounding off number

Tags: php, rounding

I need to round some numbers and get modifying value.

I've tried:

```
$Num=12.456;
$RoundDiff=$Num-round($Num,2);
$Num=round($Num,2);
echo $Num.'<br/>'.$RoundDiff;
```

but I've got:

```
12.46
-0.0040000000000013
```

while my expected result was:

```
12.46
-0.004
```

What's wrong?
How can I get what I need?

Comment: http://0.30000000000000004.com/

Comment: Nothing is wrong. `1/3` is not the same as `0.33333` no matter how many `3` we put after the decimal dot. In practice we usually tend to think they are the same thing but the latter is an approximation of the former. Computers work the same, only the numbers that can be written as `m/n` where `n` is a power of `2` can be represented exactly. All the other are approximated. It all depends how much of the error you choose to ignore.

Comment: @genespos : is your problem resolved with my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code. It will give you the expected result. I have just rounded off the difference.

```
$Num       = 12.456;
$RoundDiff = $Num-round($Num,2);
$Num       = round($Num,2);
echo $Num.'<br/>'.round($RoundDiff,3);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/zP13Mnsd)

There is issue in precision of floating point values. Refer this article for reference - [The PHP floating point precision is wrong by default](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/06/the-php-floating-point-precision-is-wrong-by-default/)

**If you want exact precision you can use [bcmath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcscale.php) or [gmp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php).**

> Because internally, computers use a format (binary floating-point)
>   that cannot accurately represent a number like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 at all.
>
> When the code is compiled or interpreted, your “0.1” is already
>   rounded to the nearest number in that format, which results in a small
>   rounding error even before the calculation happens.  — floating point
>   guide

Another Reference :

> Given that the implicit precision of a (normal) IEEE 754 double
>   precision number is slightly less than 16 digits [3](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcscale.php), this is a
>   serious overkill. Put another way, while the mantissa is composed of
>   52 bits plus 1 implicit bit, 100 decimal digits can carry up to
>   100*log2(10) =~ 332 bits of information, around 6 times more.
>
> Given this, I propose changing the default precision to 17 (while the
>   precision is slightly less than 16, a 17th digit is necessary because
>   the first decimal digit carries little information when it is low). —
>   source

**BCMATH :** *As requested in comments*

```
$a = 12.456;
$b = round($a,2);
echo 'a ='.$a.'<br>';
echo 'b ='.$b.'<br>';
echo bcsub($a, $b, 3);
```

Comment: Sorry, for late reply. I'm trying to use bcmath or gmp but I haven't yet reached my goal (I'm afraid to use the "easy and fast way") I need "rounded" + "difference" = "original Num". At the moment +1 for the explaining. If you could add code for bcmath or gmp I'll be happy to accept ;)

Comment: I have updated answer.. can you give example of what is expected.

Comment: Thanks, for extra time! Finally I used: `bcsub($Num, round($Num,2), 20);`

Comment: great. happy to help :)